# JS function params destructuring, still assign whole parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Say I have this function:

```
const myFn = obj => doSomethingWithKey(obj.key);
```

I can use destructuring, which is much more elegant:

```
const myFnV2 = ({key}) => doSomethingWithKey(key);
```

**But can I assign *within the function definition* both `key` and `obj` variables?**

Like this:

```
const otherFn = obj => {
  const {key} = obj;
  doSomethingWithObjAndKey(obj, key);
}
```

But in one line. I hoped this would work:

```
const otherFn = ({key} = obj) => doSomethingWithObjAndKey(obj, key);
```

But it doesn't as it sets obj as the default value to the `{key}` param. :(

I know that this would work:

```
const otherFn = obj => doSomethingWithObjAndKey(obj, obj.key);
```

But this reads quite differently, and the `obj.key` variable can't be used in an object directly whereas `{key}` can.

My guess is that it doesn't exists at the moment, since my research on the topic failed, but my question is: **is there such proposal for a future ES version?**

It is possible in Elixir for instance, and it is highly useful: ex. `def my_fn(%{id: id} = params)`

And it doesn't feel like much complicated to babelize, besides finding a proper syntax since `=` is already used, which *may* induce backward compatibility issues.

Comment: You can do the following: `const myFnV2 = (obj, {key}=obj) => doSomethingWithObjAndKey(obj, key);`. This basically creates a function with two parameters and initializes the second one with the value of the first one. I'm not saying that this is a good approach but it's possible.

Comment: Ugly but interesting hack! Thanks